# JQuery - Detect changes in a form & revert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect any changes a user makes to a form.

1. If the form is changed, show the save button
2. If the user puts the form back to the original, hide the save button.

It's number 2 I'm struggling with but I suspect it's my approach to number 1 that is the issue. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: where the data is come from? how did you bind the data to your form ?

Comment: You can easily do an $().on('change', function () {}); event handler on everything in the form, and when it fires, then you'll have to check every input/select/whatever(changeable) element in the form to see if it's the original value (blank?) or not. If they are all original values, hide the save button. If not, show the save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save data in each input form element by `data-*` attributes and on `input` event triggered checking each input elem. For example, HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-value="initial-value" value="initial-value">
```

JS:

```
$( 'form' ).on( 'input', ':input', function(e) {
  var $form = $(e.delegateTarget);
  var edited = false;
  $form.find( ':input' ).each( function() {
    var $this = $( this );

    if ( $this.val() === $this.data( 'value' ) ) {
       return;
    }

    $( '#save-btn' ).show();
    edited = true;
    return false;
  } );

  if ( !edited ) {
    $( '#save-btn' ).hide();
  }
} );
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, and using data- attributes is certainly a helpful approach, but it looks to me like the question is wanting a single save button that shows up if _any_ element is changed, and if no element is changed, then no save button - which would change your logic somewhat.

Comment: I used this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try by this example,

**HTML**

```
<input id="yourInput" type="text" data-value="hello" value="hello">
<input id="yourButton"type="button" value="Submit" hidden>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#yourInput').on("change paste keyup", function() {
if($('#yourInput').val() != $('#yourInput').attr("data-value"))
{ $( '#yourButton' ).show(); }
else
{ $( '#yourButton' ).hide(); }
});
```

By using this [code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/x6cob5mf/2/), your default value for input is "hello".
If you type a different value in it and the button will show.
If you type the default value "hello" again, the button will be hidden.
Hope this sample will help you.